# Jetty in eclipse - loads static content from .war

Tags: java, deployment, jetty, tapestry

I'm running Jetty from within Eclipse, installed with the Jetty Server Adaptor. I'm building a Tapestry app, and live class reloading works great. However, changes to static assets, such as images and css are not being instantly reflected: I have to do a Jetty restart-rebuild-redeploy, which is quite slow.

I think the reason for this is that my app is being deployed as a .war, and Jetty is reading static assets from here. Obviously the .war is only updated with a rebuild-redeploy.

How can I get Jetty to load static content directly from my workspace?

Thanks

Comment: try using run-jetty-run.

Comment: @pstanton: I have, and it works great. If you post as an answer I'll mark correct.

Answer (score 0):

It *might* not be possible to deploy an exploded war using the current version of the Jetty eclipse WTP plugin, at least according to [this outstanding feature request](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/JETTY-460).

An alternative solution would be to [run Jetty manually](http://www.draconianoverlord.com/2009/01/10/war-less-dev-with-jetty.html) instead of through Eclipse WTP, this would allow you to deploy the web app exploded. Although you'd need to hack a script together to copy static resources to the deployment directory as and when they change in the source folder in your eclipse project.

Answer (score 0):

Adjusting a parameter in Jetty's `webdefault.xml` named `useFileMappedBuffer` to be `false` should prevent locking of static files when running Jetty from Eclipse.